# How to debug corona sdk issue where transition.to sometimes causes both screens to show?

Tags: iphone, coronasdk

I have two files homescreen.lua and gamescreen.lua - I use transition.to to transition back and forth between these screens (No storyboard). I have (to the best of my knowledge) ensured that all display objects are under the main group for each screen (homeGroup and gameScreenGroup).

Sometimes, but not always, I get a situation (on the iPhone, not in the simulator so far) where transitioning from home screen to game screen renders the game screen on top of the home screen.

In the past, when this happened, this was fixed by finding some display object that was not added in the main group's hierarchy. However, I am unable to find any such unaccounted display object.

How do I go about debugging and fixing this?

Thanks
Anand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option i can see would be to add debug for all your display objects and check the object.parent property. If one is nil, it means that the object has no parent = no display group, and voila :)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks - what do you mean by add debug to all display objects? Sorry, am new to Corona and the only debug I have done so far is to intersperse print statements all over the code :-)

Comment: I found this link - http://www.ludicroussoftware.com/blog/2011/08/22/using-the-corona-debugger/ - do you mean set up debugging using the debugger and then break before the transition.to points and poke at all the display objects? Is there a way to get at the parentless display objects in one command?

Comment: Nope, what i mean is that the easiest way for you to debug would probably be:
#1 To add all display objects to a lua table
#2 In a convenient place, use print statements to iterate over that table and print the object.parent property for each display object.

Basically the first step is easy, everytime you create a display object you add it to a table using: 
table.insert(yourTable, yourDisplayObject)
then you use: 
for key, object in pairs(yourTable) do print(object.parent) end
In the place where you wish to debug :)

Comment: (There is no way to get all the parentless objects in one command no, you have to have the appropriate data structure to access this information by yourself :))

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it was helpful. I found the issue, turned out to be unrelated to object releases. The buttons on the homescreen were being double tapped, causing the gamescreen to be constructed twice. But since only one was being released, it led to the mayhem described. I made the buttons idempotent by adding a flag, and the issue is gone now. Thanks!